# Install java 8 and 7 RE in linux Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I already have installed in my linux Ubuntu the java 8 (Update 121), but I need to install the java 7 RE for a specific software that I need to use. I want the java 7 only to use with this tool, and I do not want to make any modification on my default java 8.
How to do that? Can I install java 7 with no issue for my 8?

```
update-alternatives --config java
   There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
    Nothing to configure.
```

Comment: This is a linux admin question; not a programming question; thus you are kinda offtopic. Just turn to askubuntu.com for example!

Comment: ok, sorry about it

Comment: But then, the answer you got is pretty good anyway; and I have seen much more off-topic questions around here many a times ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to install Java 7. You can download java 7 zip package and unzip it to a location. Create an environment variable/ Sdk Config in your tool pointing to the java 7. I am not sure which tool you are referring to !

Eg : In intellij you can create a new sdk and point it to your java 7 jdk location and use it.
     In eclipse you can create a Java 7 sdk environment from java build path and use it.

Comment: The tool is PGDspider (http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/). Can you explain more about the creation of an environment variable?

Comment: Check for Sdk Build path/Java build path under your settings/preferences in your tool and try to modify over there.